(kdb+/q) Configuring your data with tickerplant
I'm using the tick.q file found here https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick.q
I'm loading a bunch of csvs into q instance with the script below. Despite opening port to my tp the data isn't being sent to it correctly. I'm a bit stuck on how to send data via the tp when you are loading in bulk csv data as opposed to streaming data in real time.
So I essentially have all the data correctly loaded in table format on the feed instance but bit stuck as to what to do next. Can anybody offer any guidance on how to configure this?
feed.q
h:hopen`::5010

fPath:{.Q.dd [`:/Users/dt/hb/rpcoreData/histData/csvs]x}'[key `:/Users/dt/hb/rpcoreData/histData/csvs]
fPath1:{.Q.dd[x] each key x}'[fPath]
rpr:raze {("**************************";enlist",") 0: read0 each x}'[raze fPath1]

i:0
feed:{if[count[rpr]>=i;(neg h)(`.u.upd;`rpr;value rpr i);i+:1]}
.z.ts:feed

\t 100

\l /Users/dt/hb/ht/parse_scripts/parserp.q


The question is still vague/broad. Can you provide more information on the data isn't being sent correctly? Errors? Duplicates? etc.

There's no errors on the tp - the data just isn't being sent there. The "error" is essentially nothing is happening in the tp instance. My code in feed.q is supposed to be handling this. I understand the data needs to be sent in lists as opposed to tables but I'm not even making the connection despite connecting via the correct port at beginning of script

\e 1 on the tp is very useful for debugging https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#e-error-trap-clients

.z.ps:{show (`zps;.z.w;x);value x} will show you incoming messages to the TP https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zps-set

When i run that in my tp nothing happens. Does the code in my feed.q file look correct for sending data to the tp?

You're publishing data asynchronously and don't flush the output queue. I believe it might have to do with that. However, you should send the data synchronously from the feed to the TP. You can see an implementation of a simple feedhandler here https://code.kx.com/q/wp/rt-tick/#feedhandler-fh and you can read more about how tick.q works here https://www.defconq.tech/docs/tutorials/tick
Hope this helps
